# How do I send form data from my android app to firebase and basically structuring it to receive the data

Tags: android-studio, firebase

I am developing an android app, and i was wondering how would i have members register and upload files to my firebase database. I have already connected the app to firebase but the structuring of firebase is a little beyond my comprehension for now

Answer (score 0):

Firebase database is completely based on Json structure, once you understand Json structure then it would be cake walk for you in firebase.As of now to upload files you have to use firebase storage instead of firebase database.